# Does C++11 guarantee that "int a[8] = {};" is semantically equivalent to "int a[8]{};"?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, initialization, standards

In C++11, both of the following statements are legal:

statement 1. `int a[8] = {};`

statement 2. `int a[8]{};`

However, I like statement 1 better than statement 2 because I think statement 1 is more expressive.

Does the C++11 standard guarantee that both statements are semantically equivalent?

Comment: I pity anyone who has to deal with a compiler where this matters.

Comment: No, the C++ standard makes *no guarantees* about performance other than asymptotic complexity.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes but aren't the two statements equivalent? If so, an implementation would have to go out of its way to make the "performance" different. I am ignoring parsing here.

Comment: I think, in terms of *compilation* performance, statement 2 is *much* faster than the first.

Comment: @juan I agree, but that isn't a guarantee.

Comment: I seriously doubt the specification mentions anything about performance. That is up to the compiler and standard library implementer. I also doubt a good compiler would generate different code for those two declarations, but that's at least easy to find out: Compile both versions and check the generated assembly code.

Comment: And please, do *not* focus much on such micro-tunings. You'll have *much* better performance improvements if you make your overall design more efficient.

Comment: Maybe the mention of performance has clouded the issue. Perhaps the question to ask is whether the two statements are semantically equivalent (for the particular case of fixed size arrays of built-in types)?

Comment: @ta.speot.is I pity anyone who tries do deal with things that don't matter. They will matter if your profiling leads you to a hotspot, and the disassembly for that hotspot _shows_ you the compiler wasn't doing a good job with your array initialization.

Comment: @juanchopanza, you said out what I wanted to express. I've updated the original post. Thanks!

Comment: See edit per new question.

Answer (score 19):

Semantically, they are not the same, much like copy/direct initialization:

#### 8.5.4 List-initialization [dcl.init.list]

> 1 List-initialization is initialization of an object or reference from a braced-init-list. Such an initializer is
> called an initializer list, and the comma-separated initializer-clauses of the list are called the elements of the
> initializer list. An initializer list may be empty. **List-initialization can occur in direct-initialization or copyinitialization
> contexts; list-initialization in a direct-initialization context is called direct-list-initialization and
> list-initialization in a copy-initialization context is called copy-list-initialization.** [...] (emphasis mine)

Original answer, dealing with the comparative performance:
No, the standard specifies some complexity restraints on algorithms, but not performance on such issues. This is better left to the compiler, but all compilers will likely generate the same code.

Think about copy-initialization vs direct-initialization. The standard specifies only what they are, it never says one has to be faster then the other or that they must behave the same. It's entirely up to the compiler.

**And that's a good thing, because the compiler know what's best for that platform.** If the standard did impose such restraints, it could say `+` has to be faster than `*`, which is pretty intuitive. But think of a platform built for multiplication, where it's actually faster to compute `*` in machine code. The compiler would have to go out of its way to translate `*` into a slower instruction, just to conform to the standards.

Answer (score 3):

The Standard only defines so-called "observable behavior" which is the sequence of I/O library calls and reads and writes of volatile data. No speed requirements are there.

You can't be sure which is faster in practice. Decent compilers should emit the same code but sometimes there're bugs in compilers and those may affect code emission.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are semantically equivalent.

List-initialization (8.5.4) on an aggregate (8.5.1, e.g. an array) performs aggregate initialization (8.5.4p3b1).  Aggregate initialization *does not care* whether the syntactic form is that of direct-initialization or copy-initialization; the rules of aggregate initialization apply identically in either case.  In particular, the members of the aggregate are always *copy-initialized* from the corresponding clause of the initializer list.

There is an exception, which almost but not quite applies in your case; where there are insufficient elements to initialize all members of the aggregate, the standard is unclear on how to initialize the remaining members; they are list-initialized from `{}` (the empty list-initializer) but it is not specified whether they are copy-list-initialized or direct-list-initialized, or whether this depends on the original list-initialization (see comments); in fact, clang and gcc differ on their behaviour in this corner case.  However, this is irrelevant in your case, since the aggregate member type is `int`, and for nonclass types list-initialization from `{}` invokes value-initialization i.e. zero-initialization, which is direct regardless of the syntactic form (i.e., `int i{};` and `int i = {};` are semantically identical).

There are a few reasons to prefer the `=` (copy-initialization) syntax: first, it is the form used by the standard in almost all examples (the exceptions being the last two examples in 8.5.4p3, where one demonstrates an error in narrowing conversion and the other demonstrates initialization from an empty initializer-list).  Also, as you have said, it is more expressive; I also find that when list-initializing an aggregate, the copy-initialization syntax better reflects the fact that the elements of the aggregate are themselves copy-initialized.

Finally, the syntax without `=` is necessary in one case: where the object is a *non-aggregate* class type with an `explicit` constructor.  As such, the direct-list-initialization syntax should be reserved for that case.

Comment: I don't see the spec saying whether the initialization of the members is copy or direct list initialization. It just says "... then each member not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from an empty initializer list". I midly tend to agree with you based on p2 saying "Each member is copy-initialized from the corresponding initializer-clause.". However that doesn't apply for absent initializer-clauses. :) Similar to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1494 . +1 anyway because I think this answer is more accurate than the accepted one.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb ah, but initialization from an empty initializer-list can only result in aggregate initialization (for aggregates), initialization from an object of the same type (for `std::initializer_list<T>`), or value-initialization (anything else), so there's no distinction between copy- or direct-initialization.

Comment: See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1518 for why it could matter for value initialization. I have been in the impression that value initialization doesn't consider explicitness when it calls the default ctor. But RichardSmith (reporter of the issue) was in the impression that the matter isn't clear in the spec (and I sort of agree). So an issue was created, and FWIW, clang rejects value initialization with an explicit default ctor, if the value initialization was triggered by a copy list initialization.

Comment: Also, I disagree that those 3 forms are the only one that are possible. Consider `struct A { explicit A(initializer_list<int>); };` `A a = {};` is ill-formed, while `A a{};` is not.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb oh, good point.  We can use this to find what the compilers do - it seems g++ propagates direct-/copy- status into initialization of unspecified members, while clang copy-initializes them from `{}` in either case.

Answer (score 0):

The C++11 standard doesn't even guarantee that `int a[8] = {};` is as fast as `int aVeryLongName[8] = {};`.

Comment: This is hardly even comment material

Comment: @thecoshman: If you don't understand it, consider that the C++ standard makes very little assumptions about the runtime environment. In particular it allows JIT, in which the symbol parsing time could differ. A standard that mandates that two similar constructs are equally fast makes many, many more assumptions. (Note that the original, unedited question was about performance)

Comment: It's not a question of understanding what you said, it's just that what you sad does not even come close to answer this question as is only just about relevant and helpful enough to be considered a worth while comment

Comment: While I agree this isn't a good answer, I find it one of the more clever comments related to performance I've seen in a long time. I may steal it.